# Excel dynamic array formula does not spill

Tags: arrays, excel

I have some data in an Excel sheet.

[image: Some data in an Excel sheet in the range A1 to A7.]

Is there a way to write a formula that's *only* in cell B1 (cells B2:B7 are blank), that will duplicate the values in A1:A7 to the range B1:B7, using Excel's "spilling" feature for functions that return arrays?

[image: The same as the previous picture, but the data has been duplicated to the range B1 to B7.]

My first idea was to use "=A1:A7", but that just copies the value from the formula's row in column A to the cell with the formula, without affecting the other cells.

[image: The same Excel sheet. Cell B2 has the formula "=A1:A7" in it, and has the value of A2, with other cells unaffected.]

Comment: Do you have office 365?  Any version prior to Office 365, ie (Excel 2019 and older) does not have the dynamic spill array capabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
=A1:A7
```

You will need to format the resulting cells as you want.  Formula will not copy formatting and will not replace the existing formatting in the cells.

[image]

---

If your version does not have the dynamic array spill capabilities (Excel 2019 and older).  Then one will need to array enter the formula or just drag a formula down.

To array enter we select a range the same size and shape as the target and put the above formula in the formula bar:

[image]

Then we confirm the formula with Ctrl-Shift-Enter and Excel will fill the formula down the range:

[image]

But this can also be done by putting `=A1` in B1 and dragging it down.  Older version require a formula in each cell that one expects an output.  There is no "Spill" feature in older versions.

Comment: I'm using Microsoft Office 365 ProPlus, Version 1908. What's the first version that has this feature?

Comment: Have you tried updating to the new version, that one is quite old.  Not sure the exact version it was introduced but that is probably too old to have the dynamic array functionality.

Comment: It looks like it was introduced in [version 1911](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/monthly-channel-archived#version-1911-december-03). I've put in a support ticket to IT to have it updated.